# Firebase cloud messaging (FCM) in IOS app is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the documentation guide in firebase website and did all the following stuff:

**1.** Implemented the code in AppDelegate.swift.

**2.** Added the pods to my podfile and installed.

**3.** Created APN authentication key in *Certifictes, Identifiers &
            Profiles* in my developer.apple account and Paste it in the FCM settings.

**4.** Enabled Push Notification in project Capabilities (two v checked).

**5.** Created Certificate type: Apple Push Services for production

I sent couple of notifications from firebase console and didn't received any in my iPhone (IOS 10.3). **Any tips what to check? what did i miss?**

---

**Podfile**:

```
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

**AppDelegate.swift**:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Use Firebase library to configure APIs.
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        return true
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could try with Apple Push Services for development, not for production, since I suppose that you test app in debug mode, not Ad-hoc version.

Comment: Actually I found the problem in production. should I enable Background modes remote notification?

Comment: You don't need to. I receive push notifications without Background modes remote notification enabled. Background modes remote notification is used only if you need silent notifications.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a few methods.

Just compare your AppDelegate.swift with [this one](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift) :)

This is the "official" sample from the firebase-guys (I think so :D)